Struggling to Detect and Mask Flowers in Images Using OpenCV and Adaptive Thresholding
I'm working on a project where I need to detect and mask flowers in images using OpenCV and adaptive thresholding. Despite my efforts, the results are inconsistent. Some flowers are masked well, but others are either partially masked or not detected at all. I am using the Oxford Flowers 102 dataset in TensorFlow for this task. Below is the code I am using:
(train_dataset, test_dataset, validation_dataset), ds_info = tfds.load('oxford_flowers102', split=['test', 'train','validation'], with_info=True, as_supervised=True)

def normalize_img(image, label):
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (256, 256))
    return tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0, label

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.cache()
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(ds_info.splits['train'].num_examples)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(32)
train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

def detect_flowers_and_mask(image):
    image_np = (image.numpy() * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image_np, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)  
    binary_image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2) 
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    if contours:
        max_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
        mask = np.zeros_like(gray_image, dtype=np.uint8)
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [max_contour], -1, (255, 255, 255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
        masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image_np, image_np, mask=mask)
    else:
        masked_image = image_np

    return masked_image

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15)) 
for i, (image_batch, label_batch) in enumerate(train_dataset.take(20)):
    for image, label in zip(image_batch, label_batch):
        masked_image = detect_flowers_and_mask(image)
        plt.subplot(4, 5, i+1)
        plt.imshow(masked_image)
        plt.title(ds_info.features['label'].int2str(label.numpy()))  
        plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()



You might try thresholding on your black background and then invert.  Use cv2.inRange() on the background color range or simply threshold on some very low or black value. I do not think adaptive threshold is appropriate here.
